# AWS Lambda function sometimes getting error when axios call API

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-certificate-manager

My Lambda function returns errors **sometimes** when call an API. (there is 2 different APIs that Lambda calls in same time)

There is very interesting that I put some console.log's before start API call but when Lambda starts it's return error immediately without printing any log and getting 2 type errors:

```
{
    “errorType”: “Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection”,
    “errorMessage”: “Error: socket hang up”,
    “trace”: [
        “Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: socket hang up”,
        ”    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)“,
        ”    at process.emit (events.js:310:20)“,
        ”    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)“,
        ”    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)”
    ]
}


{
  “errorType”: “Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection”,
  “errorMessage”: “Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established”,
  “trace”: [
    “Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established”,
    ”    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)“,
    ”    at process.emit (events.js:310:20)“,
    ”    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)“,
    ”    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)”
  ]
}
```

**Note1**: API is another Lambda function with same domain with proxy in Api Gateway but I checked that API always returns data as expected.

**Note2:** where is no any logs in **CloudWatch** based on this error.

**Note3:** Lambda running on Node v12, RAM is more that 3000 MB, and timeout is 60 seconds.

**Note4**: I commented one of 2 API's and right now getting below error:

```
{
     "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
     "errorMessage": "Error: read ECONNRESET",
      "trace": [
      "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: read ECONNRESET",
      "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
      "    at process.emit (events.js:310:20)",
      "    at processPromiseRejections 
  (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
      "    at processTicksAndRejections 
  (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
    ]
  }
```

Handler:

```
'use strict'
console.log("in APP 1");
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
console.log("APP 2");

//express app
const app = require('./start-server');
console.log("in APP 3");

const binaryMimeTypes = [
    'application/json',
    'text/html',
];
console.log("in APP 4");

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app,null,binaryMimeTypes);

console.log("in APP 5");

exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```

**Note5:**

I can reach to APIs bu url always (as I tested right now there is no problem in responses but maybe 10 minutes later
returns error, who knows) but I start to test in Api gateway in AWS panel and sometimes start getting below error:

**Endpoint response body before transformations: {"Message":null}**

I'm not really sure that Lambda is a stable platform.

In this Lambda I'm using ExpressJS and using Sequelize as ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there is 2 different problem was in here:

- Lambda wrapping whole the application and starts handling errors such as Promise errors.

in order to prevent making **internal server error** in client side we have to mention **.catch()** after **.then()** function.

- The another problem was Lambda function that representing our API (pull data from RDS by **Sequelize** and return as **JSON**). we still getting **Message: null** error but I think it must related to **connection count** to **RDS** or **non-closed** mySQL connections.